# How to include external files in a SocialEngine module

Tags: socialengine

I have created a SocialEngine module named MyAwesomeModule that adds a signup step to existing SocialEngine signup process. It is in `application/modules/Myawesomemodule`. Besides the files in this directory, it also depends on other files e.g. several created specifically for this module and placed in `application/modules/User`. The problem that I have is that when I build a package for this module in `http://example.com/install/sdk/build`, it only includes the files residing within the module directory itself. Other files that are required for this module to work and need to be copied to external directories (`application/modules/User`) are not included in the package.

I tried adding the list of external files inside package info file i.e.`application/packages/module-myawesomemodule-4.0.0.json` before building the package as follows:

```
"application\/modules\/User": {
    "type": "directory",
    "path": "application\/modules\/User",
    "structure": [
        {
            "path": "Plugin\/Signup\/Phone.php",
            "dir": false,
            "file": true,
            "perms": "0644",
            "size": 0,
            "sha1": null
        },
        {
            "path": "Form\/Signup\/Phone.php",
            "dir": false,
            "file": true,
            "perms": "0644",
            "size": 0,
            "sha1": null
        },
        {
            "path": "controllers\/PhoneController.php",
            "dir": false,
            "file": true,
            "perms": "0644",
            "size": 0,
            "sha1": null
        }
    ]
}
```

But, the external files named in the above snippet are not copied to the package when building. Also, it seems that the external files I named in the JSON file are gone in the destination package after installation. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier than I thought, thanks to [this SocialEngine Community post](http://community.socialengine.com/forums/topic/915/how-to-include-external-files-in-a-module-before-packaging-it/view/post_id/6231).
All is required to add every file you want to your package is to include it in your manifest.php file for the module. As such:

```
return array(
    'package' =>
    array(
        'type' => 'module',
        'name' => 'advancedsmsplugin',
        'version' => '4.0.0',
        'sku' => 'com.company.sms',
        'path' => 'application/modules/Advancedsmsplugin',
        'title' => 'Advanced SMS Plugin',
        'description' => 'Advanced SMS Plugin',
        'author' => 'Company Ltd.',
        'callback' =>
        array(
            'class' => 'Engine_Package_Installer_Module',
        ),
        'actions' =>
        array(
            0 => 'install',
            1 => 'upgrade',
            2 => 'refresh',
            3 => 'enable',
            4 => 'disable',
        ),
        'directories' =>
        array(
            0 => 'application/modules/Advancedsmsplugin',
        ),
        'files' =>
        array(
            0 => 'application/languages/en/advancedsmsplugin.csv',
            1 => 'application/modules/User/Form/Signup/Phone.php',
            2 => 'application/modules/User/Plugin/Signup/Phone.php',
            3 => 'application/testpackage.html'
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```